# Windows 8, gulp calling clear

Tags: windows, gulp, windows-8

I'm using laravel elixir for running phpunit and less compilations,
but when it's running it want's to call 'clear' but that throws the error 
`{ [Error: Command failed: 'clear' is not recognized as an internal or  external command, operable program or batch file.`

this is probably due the fact that windows doesn't know the command `clear` but uses `cls` so how can I fix that gulp uses cls?

Output
[image: Error image]
grt

Comment: I can't find `clear` anywhere in the code of either gulp or elixir. Are you sure you are sure where it's coming from?

Comment: @Joey My bad, wasn't clear enough, Gulp is calling Phpunit and there is the `clear` command called, added the error output to start post

Comment: [Even PHPUnit doesn't have `clear` anywhere.](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=clear) Are you sure that's not coming from somewhere in your build scripts?

Comment: it's none of my scripts like I mentioned they are from laravel elixir.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue !!!  my bad , copied some stuff from the internet ...
there was a gulp.js file on the root of my project...

look for a line :
     .pipe(run('clear'))

I just comment the clear out and replace with cls

Hope it works...